# is there a python (or matlab) function that achieves the minimum MSE between given set of output vector and calculated set of vector?

Tags: python, matlab, optimization

I have some simple problem to solve, and wonder if there is any smarter/better way to achieve the following:

Here is the scenario. I have a set of given vector 'h(x)' and two functions, f(x,a) and g(x,b). These two functions take argument 'a' and 'b', and create 1-D vectors.
Now, I want to compare the given vector 'h(x)' to a vector created by adding f(x,a) and g(x,b). my ultimate goal is finding the argument 'a' and 'b' that yields the minimum MSE between vector 'h(x)' and a vector of f(x,a)+g(x,b).

What would be the best way to achieve this?

The current solution I came up is simply sweeping the argument 'a' and 'b' for some arbitrary range, manually calculate the MSE, then find the 'a' and 'b' that achieves the minimum MSE.

I wonder if there is better/more convenient way to do this.

Thank you,

Comment: This seems quite generic to have a closed form solution. Have you considered doing `gradient descent` after establishing the objective-fn? That might be your best bet

Comment: @SerialLazer thanks for your suggestion. I was able to solve the problem with your comment & falopsy's response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an objective function that takes a and b as the input parameters and output a measure of fit (mse) and then use one of MATLAB in-built functions to minimise the error to get the best a and b. I have quickly create an example code below. You can modify it. Read more about fmincon - it allows you to put constraints on the solution etc.

```
function [a,b] = optimize_ab(x, h,f,g)
% h= h(x) should take vector x and yield vector output
% f=f(x,a)
% g=g(x,b)
% x: input vector
% ========================================================
% Example: find a function to approximate f=x^2 with a*x^1.5+b*x^2.5
% x=1:4;
% h(x)=x.^2;
% f=@(x,a)a*x.^1.5;
% g(x)=g=@(x,b)b*x.^2.5;
% [a,b] = optimize_ab(x,h,f,g)
%=========================================================
h_=h(x);
N =length(x);
res = fmincon(@MSE, [0,0], [], []);
a=res(1);
b=res(2);

    function mse = MSE(x_)
        a_=x_(1);
        b_=x_(2);
        mse =sqrt(sum((h_-(f(x,a_)+g(x,b_))).^2)/N);
    end
end
```

Comment: really appreciate your help! this code worked with a minor modification:
the only change I've made is changing the last line of function mse to 
mse = norm(h_ - (f(x, a_) + g(x,b_))); 
I'm leaving this comment for future reference. Thanks!!!

Comment: You are right. I misplaced a bracket somewhere - I have corrected it. I don't have a matlab on my computer to test. norm works as well. I am glad it helps you.