# Fitting Data with Linear Combination of Vectors in MATLAB with Constraints

Tags: matlab, optimization, solver, data-fitting

Working in MATLAB. I have the following equation:

S = aW + bX + cY + dZ

where S,W,X,Y, and Z are all known n x 1 vectors. I am trying to fit the data of S with a linear combination of the basis vectors W,X,Y, and Z with the constraint of the constants (a,b,c,d) being greater than 0. I have managed to do this in Excel's solver, and have attempted to figure it out on MATLAB, being directed towards functions like *fmincon*, but I am not overly familiar with MATLAB and feel I am misunderstanding the use of *fmincon*.

I am looking for help with understanding fmincon's use towards my problem, or redirection towards a more efficient method for solving.

Currently I have:

```matlab
initials = [0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2];
fun = @(x)x(1)*W + x(2)*X + x(3)*Y + x(4)*Z;
lb = [0,0,0,0];
soln = fmincon(fun,initials,data,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub);
```

I am receiving an error stating "A must have 4 column(s)". Where A is referring to my variable data which corresponds to my S in the above equation. I do not understand why it is expecting 4 columns. Also to note the variables that are in my above snippet that are not explicitly defined are defined as [], serving as space holders.

Comment: Please specify what you need help with. "Any help is appreciated" is [too broad for Stack Overflow](/help/on-topic). It would help if you included your attempt as a [mre] and described why it didn't work. Remember to include full stack traces if relevant! Here's a helpful [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is similar to the answer I gave at [is there a python (or matlab) function that achieves the minimum MSE between given set of output vector and calculated set of vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64725323/is-there-a-python-or-matlab-function-that-achieves-the-minimum-mse-between-giv/64730587#64730587).

The procedure is similar to what you are doing in EXCEL with solver. You create an objective function that takes (a, b, c, d) as the input parameters and output a measure of fit (mse) and then use fmincon or similar solver to get the best (a, b, c, d) that minimize this mse. See the code below (no MATLAB to test it but it should work).

```
function [a, b, c, d] = optimize_abcd(W, X, Y, Z)
%=========================================================
%Second argument is the starting point, second to the last argument is the lower bound 
%to ensure the solutions are all positive
res = fmincon(@MSE, [0,0,0,0], [], [], [], [], [0,0,0,0], []);
a=res(1);
b=res(2);
c=res(3);
d=res(4);

    function mse = MSE(x_)
        a_=x_(1);
        b_=x_(2);
        c_=x_(3);
        d_=x_(4);
        S_ = a_*W + b_*X + c_*Y + d_*Z
        mse = norm(S_-S);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Using fmincon is a huge overkill in this case. It's like using big heavy microscope to crack nuts... or martian rover to tow a pushcart or... anyway :) May be it's OK if you don't have to process large sets of vectors. If you need to fit hundreds of thousands of such vectors it can take hours. But this classic solution will be faster by several orders of magnitude.

```
%first make a n x 4 matrix of your vectors;
P=[W,X,Y,Z];
% now your equation looks like this S = P*m where m is 4 x 1 vectro
% containing your coefficients ( m = [a,b,c,d] )
% so solution will be simply
m_1 = inv(P'*P)*P'*S;
% or you can use this form
m_2 = (P'*P)\P'*S;
% or even simpler
m_3 = (S'/P')';
% all three solutions should give exactly same resul
% third solution is the neatest but may not work in every version of matlab

% Your modeled vector will be
Sm = P*m_3; %you can use any of m_1, m_2 or m_3;
% And your residual 
R = S-Sm;
```

If you need to procees many vectors don't use for cycle. For cycles are very slow in Matlab and you should use matrices instead, if possible. S can also be n*k matrix, where k is number vectors you want to process. In this case m will be 4*k matrix.